# PHP & MySQL UPDATE 10 columns

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

I want to update customer data which means 10 different columns would be updated in one UPDATE SET WHERE statement but I keep getting a warning in NetBeans that says method length 26 ( allowed 20)
Can anyone tell me what the method length refers to and what another way is to update all those columns in one statement ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an utterly ridiculous hint. You can disable it in 
Tools->Options->Editor->Hints->PHP. 
It won't disturb you again.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is notorious for these informational messages which are really a matter of style preference rather than an actual limitation.

I like to create my SQL code directly using a tool like phpMyAdmin to verify the statement works then port it over to my code.

Comment: Well I tried it with updating only 5 columns which worked out but as soon as I add more it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Did you try it in Netbeans or directly in your database?

Can you share more details of your query?

Comment: I tried to add a photo but apparently the size is too large.

Comment: How can I add code in here? It's the first time I'm using this website lol

Comment: I tried it in NetBeans I'll try it in phpmyAdmin now

Comment: Copy and paste - 4 spaces in front of text indicates it's code, and note the other answer about disabling this warning.

Comment: It worked in phpmyAdmin so I just copied the query and pasted it to NetBeans and it seems to work now  Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, I suggest you download and install mysql workbench, it will serve as sandbox to test queries before anything else. This always works for me in any development situations